# jQuery click event triggered twice when clicking on Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click

I'm playing around with *DataTables* and I have a table like this :

```
<table id='dt'>
    <thead><!-- Some Header --></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-lineid=1>
            <td><input type='checkbox' class='checked_entry' id='checked_1'></td>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Rest of the table -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What I am trying to do is to be able to click everywhere in the row, and it will select the checkbox of this row :

```
$('#dt tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('lineid');
    if ($('#checked_'+id).prop('checked')) {
        $('#checked_'+id).prop('checked', false);
    } else {
        $('#checked_'+id).prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

This is working fine, except that now, when I'm clicking on the checkbox itself, it seems it triggers the checkbox click event *plus* the event bound on the `tr`.

I've tried something like :

```
$('#dt tbody').on('click', 'tr :not(input)', function() { ... });
```

But this seems not to work.

Could anyone give me a tip on this please ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to exit the `tr` click event whenever the user is making a click on checkbox,

```
$('#dt tbody').on('click', 'tr', function(e) {
    if($(e.target).is('input')) { return; }
    var id = $(this).data('lineid');
    if ($('#checked_'+id).prop('checked')) {
        $('#checked_'+id).prop('checked', false);
        // ... and some other stuff
    } else {
        $('#checked_'+id).prop('checked', true);
        // ... and some other stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because the click event on the checkbox itself is propagated. As a solution you can check whether the actual click target was the checkbox in that case don't do anything in the click handler.

```
$('#dt tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('input:checkbox')) {
        $(this).find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', function (i, checked) {
            return !checked;
        })
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6graj/)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, remove the iterative identifier you don't need it; at least not solely for identifying the row containing a checkbox.

```
<table id='dt'>
    <thead><!-- Some Header --></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='checkbox' class='checked_entry' /></td>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then in jQuery you can attach your event to the `tr` using traversal to find the related checkbox, and also use `stopPropagation()` on the click of the checkbox to stop the event being caught twice.

```
$('#dt tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    var $checkbox = $(this).find(':checkbox');
    $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox.prop('checked'));
});
$('#dt input:checkbox').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4t7Bt/)

Comment: I need the identifier for other purposes that I didn't paste here. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Fair point. It can easily be added back in, but you don't require it for checking/unchecking the boxes of a related `tr`

Comment: Sure, no excuses on that :) I'll use your solution to check/uncheck ! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could make sure the click event doesn't propagate to the row element when you click the checkbox like this:

```
$('#dt tbody input').on('click', function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$('#dt tbody').on('click', 'tr', function(event) {
    var id = $(this).data('lineid');
    if ($('#checked_'+id).prop('checked')) {
        $('#checked_'+id).prop('checked', false);
    } else {
        $('#checked_'+id).prop('checked', true);
    }
      event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#dt tbody').on('click', 'tr', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('lineid');
    if ($('#checked_'+id).prop('checked')) {
        $('#checked_'+id).prop('checked', false);
    } else {
        $('#checked_'+id).prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you already have table row click event.It will also be fired when checkbox click and here you are changing the state of checkbox in your click event.So it is better to preventDefault() event of checkbox.A better solution would be:

```
$('#dt tbody').on('click', 'tr', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var id = $(this).data('lineid');
if ($('#checked_'+id).prop('checked')) {
    $('#checked_'+id).prop('checked', false);
    // ... and some other stuff
} else {
    $('#checked_'+id).prop('checked', true);
    // ... and some other stuff
}
});
```